# Reading huge Txt in C

Tags: c, text, vector

I want to read a text file with more than 5.5M of lines, however, for test proposes, I just read one with 900 lines and 70 columns and stored it in a `matrix x[1000][100]`.

I am doing this because I want to recognize the 13th column of my text file that contains the number of the day. Further I will split this text in many other text files containing the data from each day.

I will create another text file with the same values and, each time the 13th column changes, I will write a message saying `"NEW DAY"`. After this, I will use the other software to track this `"NEW DAY"` and split when it find one.

Everything is working well until the `line 385`, remember that each line has about `70 columns`, however, after this value I don't know why the file stops to recognize the changing in the `13th column` of each line and just stop writing `"NEW DAY"` when the number changes.

The data is shown in this way:

```
TAM 2000-03-07T16:55    22.78   5.50999 2   110 1   233 2.2 65  0.3 293 0
```

Where the number behind the T, is the one I want to track.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    long int i = 0;
    long int j = 0;
    char x[1000][100];
    FILE *file = fopen("Entrada.txt", "r");
    FILE *file2 = fopen("Saida.txt", "w");

    while ((x[i][j] = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        if(i>=1 && j==70) {
            if(x[i][13] != x[i-1][13]) {
                for(j=0; j <= 70;j++) {
                    fprintf(file2, "%c", x[i-1][j]);
                    printf("%c", x[i-1][j]);
                    if(j==70){
                        fprintf(file2, "\n %s \n","New Line");
                        printf("\n %s \n","New Line");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for(j=0; j <= 70 ;j++) {
                    fprintf(file2, "%c", x[i][j]);
                    printf("%c", x[i][j]);
                    if(j==70) {
                        fprintf(file2, "\n %s \n","");
                        printf("\n %s \n","");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(x[i][j] =='\n'){
            i++;
            j=0;
        } else {
            j++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you store all lines in an array? When not just process the file line-by-line?

Comment: I don't know how can i store line by line. For me i just have to compare one line with the line before and then write the stuffs in another text file.

About the dynamic memory allocation, well, sorry for this but, i don't know where should i use it. I mean, i should use it to create a bigger matrix? Because i can read the entire matrix, the problem is that after sometime it just stop verifying the columns.

Comment: Forget my first comment (I just deleted it). Your program is terribly complicated, just read the file line by line using `fgets` and process the lines as you read them. You don't need to store everything in an array.

Comment: Thank you Michael, i will try to do it now. Really thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state in your question that you need to check the 13th character to see if the day changed, but it seems you only check one digit in the day. Days can have two digits.

In C array index is 0 based so based on your sample input it looks like index
12 and 13 should be checked i.e. column 13 and 14.

You do not need to store all rows and compare, just store the information that changes i.e. the two characters that tell you the day.

You could try something like this instead:

```
char line[100];
char old12 = ' ';
char old13 = ' ';
long row = 0;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1) != NULL)
{
  if (row++>0)
  {
    if (line[12] != old12 || line[13] != old13)
    {
      /* remove \n */
      char* nl = strchr(line,'\n');
      if (nl) *nl = '\0';
      fprintf(file2,"%s", line );
      fprintf(file2, " New Line\n" );
    }
    else
    {
      fprintf(file2,line);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(file2,line);
  }
  old12 = line[12];
  old13 = line[13];
}
```

Having a large two-dimensional array is bound to cause you problems if you are processing a large file, instead try to keep as little of the text in memory as possible.

You didn't describe your data but if there are gaps in the data you may want to check the whole date instead of just the day otherwise rows like this would not be detected:

```
TAM 2000-03-07T16:55    22.78   5.50999 2   110 1   233 2.2 65  0.3 293 0
TAM 2000-04-07T16:55    22.78   5.50999 2   110 1   233 2.2 65  0.3 293 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, you gave me an idea as well. I just checked one of the last number of the day because even if you have two digits, when the day change, the last digit will always be different from the last day. Even if it were 09 and then pass to 10, the last digit will change from 9 to 0. About the data, they are lots of lines like one i used as a sample, they are 30.000 files with 44640 rows and fixed 67 columns.

Answer (score 0):

People, i found a solution for my problem and it worked with huge files with more than 17 millions of rows.

Here is the code, it is very big and, probably, i have made many not necessary things since i am not expert with C.

Thank you all for the help, here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int TAM_BUFFER = 75; 
int TAM_BUFFER2 = 75; 
int count = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *arquivo = fopen("ConcatenatedFiles.txt", "r");
FILE *saida = fopen("Saida.txt", "w");

char buffer[TAM_BUFFER];
char buffer2[TAM_BUFFER2];

if(arquivo != NULL){

while(fgets(buffer, TAM_BUFFER, arquivo)){
    
        if(count==0){
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
         }
    
        count++;

        
        if(count>1){
            if(buffer2[13]!=buffer[13]){
                printf("%s\n", buffer2);
                printf("%s\n", "NEW DAY");
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
                
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer2);
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", "NEW DAY");
            }
            else{
                if(buffer2[12]!=buffer[12]){
                printf("%s\n", buffer2);
                printf("%s\n", "NEW DAY");
                printf("%s\n", buffer);
                
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer2);
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", "NEW DAY");
                }
                else{
                    printf("%s\n", buffer2);
                    printf("%s\n", buffer);
                
                    fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer2);
                    fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer);
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(count>=1){
        fgets(buffer2, TAM_BUFFER2, arquivo) ;

      }
      
        if(count=1){
            if(buffer[13]!=buffer2[13]){
                printf("%s\n", "NEW DAY");
                
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer);
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", "NEW DAY");
            }
            else{
                if(buffer[12]!=buffer2[12]){
                printf("%s\n", "NEW DAY");
                
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", buffer);
                fprintf(saida,"%s\n", "NEW DAY");
                }   
            }
          }
}
printf("%s\n", buffer2);

fclose(arquivo);
fclose(saida);
}
else
 printf("Not possible to open the file.");

printf("\n\n");
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```